# Difference between 2 consecutive values in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have the following script:

```
let StartTime = datetime(2022-02-18 10:10:00 AM);
let EndTime = datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM);
MachineEvents
| where Timestamp between (StartTime .. EndTime)
| where Id == "00112233" and Name == "Higher"
| top 2 by Timestamp
| project Timestamp, Value
```

I got the following result:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve after that is to check if the last Value received (in this case for example it is 15451.433) is less than 30,000. If the condition is true, then I should check again the difference between the last two consecutive values (in this case : 15451.433 - 15457.083). If the difference is < 0 then I should return the Value as true, else it should return as false (by other words the Value should give a boolean value instead of double as shown in the figure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Value:double)
[
 datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 15457.083,
 datetime(2022-02-18 10:14:00 AM), 15451.433,
 datetime(2022-02-18 10:13:00 AM), 15433.333,
 datetime(2022-02-18 10:12:00 AM), 15411.111
]
| top 2 by Timestamp
| project Timestamp, Value
| extend nextValue=next(Value)
| extend finalResult = iff(Value < 30000, nextValue - Value < 0, false)
| top 1 by Timestamp
| project finalResult
```

Output:

| finalResult |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how come the next value is the value coming from minute 14. Shouldn't be the next value = 15451.433

Comment: In my example, 15451.433 is related to the highest timestamp. To align it with your example, just switch the values of the 'Value' column in the first two lines. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: What I meant is that if I run your code and project nextValue I will be getting an answer 15,457.083. I think that the next value should be the one with highest timestamp no ? So in this case 15,451.433. It should give you the next value depending on the timestamp. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: I just put an arbitrary values in my 'datatable'. I edited the example to align it with yours.

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing you, but I think instead of nextValue - Value in finalResult it should be Value - NextValue because the NextValue variable has a value from a timestamp which is lower than the latest timestamp. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`prev()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction) function (or `next()`) to process the values in the other rows.

```
...
| extend previous = prev(value)
| extend diff = value - previous
| extend isPositive = diff > 0
```

You might need to use [serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions#serialized-row-set) if you don't have something like `top` that already does that for you.

Comment: The results are already serialized since the query has "top"

Comment: Good point, I adapted the answer

Comment: @AlexAIT Thank you for your answer. The thing that I am not understanding is why when using prev(value) I am getting the value 15,451.433. I should be getting the other number since the timestamp of the latter was before.